# How to access removable storage on Android devices?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I am looking for a way to detect and access removable sd cards on a variety of Android devices (Samsung, Motorola, LG, Sony, HTC).

I also need to be compatible with 2.2 so `Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable()` is unavailable for me.

Motorola has its own library, and for Samsung I can detect the existence of `/external_sd/`

I have no clue for the rest of them. For example, I have seen a `/_ExternalSD/` on some LG's but it the directory remains even when the SD is removed.

A bonus question: will the `ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED` intent be broadcast for any of them

Any hint on this would be very helpful.

Comment: Anything beyond the methods on `Environment` is beyond the bounds of the SDK and will be unreliable.

Comment: But given that there is no more reliable way to access removable storage via the API, if accessing the SD card is a requirement, any method that mostly works is better than none.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a class I use to find all sdcards on a device; built in and removable. I've been using it on Ice Cream Sandwich, but it should work at 2x levels.

```
public class GetRemovableDevice {

private final static String TAG = "GetRemoveableDevice";

public GetRemovableDevice() {
}

public static String[] getDirectories() {
    MyLog.d(TAG, "getStorageDirectories");
    File tempFile;
    String[] directories = null;
    String[] splits;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    String lineRead;

    try {
        arrayList.clear(); // redundant, but what the hey
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/mounts"));

        while ((lineRead = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            MyLog.d(TAG, "lineRead: " + lineRead);
            splits = lineRead.split(" ");

            // System external storage
            if (splits[1].equals(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getPath())) {
                arrayList.add(splits[1]);
                MyLog.d(TAG, "gesd split 1: " + splits[1]);
                continue;
            }

            // skip if not external storage device
            if (!splits[0].contains("/dev/block/")) {
                continue;
            }

            // skip if mtdblock device

            if (splits[0].contains("/dev/block/mtdblock")) {
                continue;
            }

            // skip if not in /mnt node

            if (!splits[1].contains("/mnt")) {
                continue;
            }

            // skip these names

            if (splits[1].contains("/secure")) {
                continue;
            }

            if (splits[1].contains("/mnt/asec")) {
                continue;
            }

            // Eliminate if not a directory or fully accessible
            tempFile = new File(splits[1]);
            if (!tempFile.exists()) {
                continue;
            }
            if (!tempFile.isDirectory()) {
                continue;
            }
            if (!tempFile.canRead()) {
                continue;
            }
            if (!tempFile.canWrite()) {
                continue;
            }

            // Met all the criteria, assume sdcard
            arrayList.add(splits[1]);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    } finally {
        if (bufferedReader != null) {
            try {
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    // Send list back to caller

    if (arrayList.size() == 0) {
        arrayList.add("sdcard not found");
    }
    directories = new String[arrayList.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
        directories[i] = arrayList.get(i);
    }
    return directories;
}
```

}

The MyLog.d is a trace class that expands Log.d - it can be dropped.

The class reads /proc/mounts/ and:

1. checks to see if the path name is the internal sdcard directory
2. checks to see if its a block device
3. skips mtdblock devices
4. skips anything that is not mounted
5. skips secure and asec directories
6. makes sure it exists, is a directory, and read/write accessible

If all this is matched, it assumes that you have an sdcard and adds the path to the array list. It returns a string array of path names.

To call the getDirectories function, code something similar to:

```
String[] sdcardDirectories = GetRemoveableDevice.getDirectories();
```

The paths returned can be used to create a user selection list, scan for a file, or whatever.

Finally, here's two lines of MyLog.d from an emulator test (second line is the emulator sdcard):

09-19 15:57:12.511: D/GetRemoveableDevice(651): lineRead: /dev/block/mtdblock2 /cache yaffs2 rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0

09-19 15:57:12.511: D/GetRemoveableDevice(651): lineRead: /dev/block/vold/179:0 /mnt/sdcard vfat rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,uid=1000,gid=1015,fmask=0702,dmask=0702,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0

Comment: Ooops. I forgot to mention that checking the read/write status eliminates unmounted sdcards that still have an entry in the /mnt/ directory.

Comment: I know this thread is old, but I'm converting some storage detection code into a general purpose library and want to distinguish between external storage that is permanent and that which is actually removable.  I don't know if your solution meets that requirement?  It seems that the first "if" statement in your loop will store any occurrence of the path returned by "getExternalStorageDirectory()", which more often than not is NOT physically removable, right?

Comment: Sorry to take so long. Heads down at keyboard working on project. To answer, yes the path from getExtenalStorageDirectory is normally the unmountable sdcard. The first entry in the list returned is the getExternal sdcard. If the list has multiple entries, use the second or later entry. You can also check to see if it can be dismounted. Also, you can make a simple project to display the list (and whatever else you want) and then check what happens when you remove and replace the removeable sdcard(s).

Comment: Does not work out of the box on Galaxy S3. I made some changes. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Howards class I made some modifications to make it work on the Galaxy S3.

1. Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() returns internal storage on the S3.
2. Removable storage is not necessarily mounted under /mnt
3. Removable media must have vfat filesystem

_

```
public static String getDirectory() {
        Log.d(TAG, "getStorageDirectories");
        File tempFile;
        String[] splits;
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        String lineRead;

        try {
            arrayList.clear(); // redundant, but what the hey
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/mounts"));

            while ((lineRead = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "lineRead: " + lineRead);
                splits = lineRead.split(" ");

                // skip if not external storage device
                if (!splits[0].contains("/dev/block/")) {
                    continue;
                }

                // skip if mtdblock device
                if (splits[0].contains("/dev/block/mtdblock")) {
                    continue;
                }

                // skip if not in vfat node
                if (!splits[2].contains("vfat")) {
                    continue;
                }

                // skip these names
                if (splits[1].contains("/secure")) {
                    continue;
                }

                if (splits[1].contains("/mnt/asec")) {
                    continue;
                }

                // Eliminate if not a directory or fully accessible
                tempFile = new File(splits[1]);
                if (!tempFile.exists()) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (!tempFile.isDirectory()) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (!tempFile.canRead()) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (!tempFile.canWrite()) {
                    continue;
                }

                // Met all the criteria, assume sdcard
                return splits[1];
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        } finally {
            if (bufferedReader != null) {
                try {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I agree it is a hack. But this is the cleanest hack I have seen. If you find a proper way please let us know.

Comment: how is different form the one i posted

Comment: it is reading from a virtual file instead of spawning processes.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Howards class I modified the class further on noticing that all of the external removable storage on several phones and tablets that I could find were mounted using vold, the volume mounting daemon.

```
            // skip if not external storage device
            if (!splits[0].contains("vold")) {
                continue;
            }

            if (splits[1].contains("/mnt/asec")) {
                continue;
            }

            // Eliminate if not a directory or fully accessible
            tempFile = new File(splits[1]);
            if (!tempFile.exists()) {
                continue;
            }
            if (!tempFile.isDirectory()) {
                continue;
            }
            if (!tempFile.canRead()) {
                continue;
            }
            if (!tempFile.canWrite()) {
                continue;
            }

            // Met all the criteria, assume sdcard
            arrayList.add(splits[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing what you've learned. +1. Please remember that "above" is not a stable property of answers... there are currently 3 other classes on this page, and the 2 classes you're referring to may appear below yours when someone views this page.

Answer (score 1):

These capabilities are available in all Android versions:

- To obtain the application's folder on the external storage, call [`Context.getExternalFilesDir`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)).
- Keep in mind that your app needs explicit permission to access external storage, and that you should check if it is available via [`Environment.getExternalStorageState`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageState())
- And yes, `ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED` will be broadcast whenever removable media becomes accessible (You should also listen for `ACTION_MEDIA_EJECT` and `ACTION_MEDIA_REMOVED`)

Comment: Thanks Tony but this will only return /mnt/sdcard which is not the removable storage device. I have edited my question so it is accurately formulated.

Comment: Yes, external storage is *usually*, but not *always* removable. What is your exact use case?

Comment: The app must provide a choice of storage devices for downloads. Typically internal vs external removable storage device. From what I see the separation is not that clear. E.g. Samsung mounts the removable sd on /mnt/sdcard/external_sd. LG on /mnt/sdcard/_ExternalSD/ but the dir and some files remains even if the removable is unplugged. Which suggest that there is no logical separation

Comment: You are correct, there is no distinction of removable/non-removable prior to 2.3.  Are there any actual devices that have *both* types of storage (and aren't running 2.3 or above)?

Comment: I have 2 quite recent LG phones with external storage and 2.2 on my desk

Comment: What are the mounting paths for their built-in external storage? Specifically, which path does `Context.getExternalFilesDir` return?

Answer (score 1):

This is the method I created and am using.  This has worked on Samsung Galaxy S4, Samsung Galaxy Note 3 and Sony Xperia Z2.

```
private static String[] getRemovableStoragePaths() {
    String[] directories;
    String[] splits;
    ArrayList<String> pathList = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    String lineRead;

    try {
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/mounts"));

        while ((lineRead = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "lineRead: " + lineRead);
            splits = lineRead.split(" ");
            Log.d(TAG, "Testing path: " + splits[1]);

            if (!splits[1].contains("/storage")) {
                continue;
            }

            if (splits[1].contains("/emulated")) {
                // emulated indicates an internal storage location, so skip it.
                continue;
            }

            // Eliminate if not a directory or fully accessible
            Log.d(TAG, "Path found: " + splits[1]);

            // Met all the criteria, assume sdcard
            pathList.add(splits[1]);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    } finally {
        if (bufferedReader != null) {
            try {
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    // Send list back to caller

    if (pathList.size() == 0) {
        pathList.add("sdcard not found");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Found potential removable storage locations: " + pathList);
    }
    directories = new String[pathList.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < pathList.size(); i++) {
        directories[i] = pathList.get(i);
    }
    return directories;
}
```